# Content assist Statet

Tags: eclipse, r

I have 2 questions about Statet/Eclipse content assist:

1. Is it possible to tweak the order of the suggestions? One possibility would be to have the most used ones on top, instead of just alphabetical order...
2. When debugging (with "browser") the content assist is not suggesting the objects in the "debug" environment. Is there a way to fix that?

Regards

Comment: I doubt the ordering is StatET specific, most probably has something to do with the generic Eclipse suggestion system (sorry, not sure how it is called). Unfortunately I can't help you there...

Answer (score 0):

I think, what you are looking for is this: http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/

One of their slides pretty much explains what it does:

[image: Slide N° 5]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/slideshow/cc05.png))</sub>

Download it here http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/download/

Answer (score 0):

(sorry, can't comment on existing post yet)

Is this kind of ranking what you are looking for or do you need an approach that "just remembers" what you have used before?

You may consider to describe your need with little more detail here http://www.eclipse.org/forums/eclipse.recommenders  ?